# YU Yureka freezes and reboots since the last Lollipop upgrade 5.1.1

Tags: system-freeze, micromax-yu-yureka

I have YU Yureka. I upgraded it to Lollipop 5.1.1 last week.

Since then, the screen goes blank most of the time whenever I open any application and then it comes back in few seconds and phone restarts automatically many times.
Please can you help me out about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If this happens after an update you should do a factory reset from the recovery menu and clean your partition cache. Some malfunctions like this is expected in most of the devices after a system upgrade or firmware upgrade. It is always good to clean partition cache after every firmware update.

If you don't know how to perform a factory reset from the recovery menu and to clean partition cache just google it. You should back up all the needed data before factory reset because it will erase everything in your device.